# Api result isn't being rendered to page

Tags: reactjs, submit

I'm using the pokeapi to return basic information about a pokemon from the pokeapi. Nothing is being rendered to the component. Not even the default value passed as a parameter(pikachu). When I inpspect the XHR response with the dev tools, a response object is being returned but it's not being displayed. Any suggestions?

I have a link to the sandbox code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mountain-jvbwc?file=undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh i see the issue

You need to change your `searchPokemon` method to use an arrow function because [non-arrow functions are not `this` binding](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-to-use-arrow-functions/).

[image: bad method]

Another issue, you should update you catch statement to use `console.error` so you can see the error message in the console.